# soap api is not working in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, products, soap, soap-api-v2

I am trying to get products using soap api. But I am getting below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1' : failed to load
>   external entity "https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1"
>   in /var/www/example/soap.php:36 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/example/soap.php(36):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('https://example...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/example/soap.php on line 36

I am using below code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');

var_dump($client); die('test');
```

Also, I have reinstalled openssl and ca-certificates on the server.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Check if soap is enabled in the server or not?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Soap is enabled

Comment: Are you using live server or in local?

Comment: It is live server

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in aws server with ubuntu OS.

I have resolved the issue by applying following lines.

Add the below lines to your working php.ini file:

```
verify_peer = false
verify_peer_name = false
allow_self_signed = false
```

Just above the below lines

```
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:
```

You can see the above lines at the end of the php.ini file.

Update these are restart the apache. It should work.